# Is it not possible to add text to a single JTextArea dynamically?

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

i am developing a GUI using Java Swing. but i got stuck here. 
Is it not possible to add text to the single "JTextArea" dynamically?

Ex:

```
class Sample extends JFrame{

    public static void fn(int n) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        f.add(ta);
        f.setVisible(true);
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
           //some processing is done
         ta.setText(" step is done");
           // some other stuffs  
        }  
    }
}
```

this is just part of my source code. My problem here is , in this code for each iteration of the "for loop" i am getting a new frame with the text " step is done".  but instead i want it to be displayed on a single frame 'n; times.

Comment: What do you mean by getting a new frame? You are not creating another instance of JTextArea in that for loop.

Comment: I think we need the code in the loop to understand your problem better. `ta.setText()` should normally modify the text in the TextArea and not create a new frame, but when you use it in the loop I'd expect you'll see only the last text that you set, since you block the UI thread.

Comment: ta.setText(ta.getText() + "SomeString") //if needed for new line use LineSeparator or for Win OS just \n

Comment: @ Hovercraft Full Of Eels that's never important because it will eventually prove that it was only and only just critical  :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setText()` method sets the text, not appends its. You'll have to do that manually:

```
ta.setText(ta.getText() + "\nStep is done.");
```

#### EDIT:

My bad, I didn't use Swing for a while and simply forgot about such a basic thing as `append()`. You should accept @Hovercraft Full Of Eels answer as it's a correct and much better one.

Comment: @Crozin isn't there also an append method as well?

Comment: @DazSlayer - there is, `append`.

Comment: i just now tried doing as u mentioned. but still i am getting the results in different frames

Comment: @Sachin: Please read the comments on your original post and modify your original post so that we can see the important stuff you left out.

Comment: -1, As people have already mentioned the append(...) method exists for this purpose. Resetting the text is inefficient. First of all you need to rebuild the text String from the Document, then when you reset the text you need to reparse the string into separate lines.

Answer (score 3):

I would change your code to:

```
class Sample { // no need to extend JFrame here

    public static void fn(int n) {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        f.add(ta);
        f.setVisible(true);
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

           // ... *** don't create a new JFrame here ***

           ta.append(" step is done\n");

           // ... *** and don't create a new JFrame here ***

        }  
    }
}
```

We'll be able to give you more details if/when you show us what you're doing in the commented out bits in your original post's code.

Comment: @Sachin: You're welcome.  Please let us know what the error was and how you fixed it.

Comment: @Sachin:  Good suggestion by HFOE to explain the solution you came to.  That helps others searching later on the same problem.  Another thing that will help them is to mark the answer as 'correct', so that it is put at the top of the answer list.

Answer (score 2):

```
import javax.swing.*;

// don't extend JFrame unless adding functionality
//class Sample extends JFrame{
class Sample {

    JTextArea ta;

    Sample() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        ta = new JTextArea(10,35);
        // to look better
        ta.setLineWrap(true);
        ta.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        //should be in a JScrollPane
        f.add(ta);
        // important
        f.pack();
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void fn(int n) {
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){
           //some processing is done
         ta.append(" step is done");
           // some other stuffs
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Sample sample = new Sample();
                sample.fn(40);
            }
        });
    }
}
```